# How to generate a button exactly NEXT TO another button?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, location, logic

I created separate class with custom button, which i want to be poped when this "newButton" is clicked.
How do i do it manually? so if there is multiple "newButtons" and i want to hide previous apeared Custom Buttons
My problem is that i dont know how to seek locations of the new buttons because it is in flowLayout which puts them automatically.

```cs
Button newButton = new Button();
newButton.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(50)))), ((int)(((byte)(175)))), ((int)(((byte)(241)))));
newButton.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 2;
newButton.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
newButton.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10.2F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
newButton.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
newButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(158, 288);
newButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 38);
newButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
newButton.Text = k.grp;

newButton.Click += (sender, e) => newButton_Click(sender, e);

if (checkinNames.Contains(newButton.Text))
{ }
else
    flowLayoutPanel5.Controls.Add(newButton);

checkinNames.Add(k.grp);
```

Comment: What UI framework are you using?

Comment: Windows Form App .Net Framework

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve it by specific property directly in FlowLayoutPanel. All visual controls placed in it will automatically adjust their positions according to the size of the FlowLayoutPanel.

Here is a workaround via setting button `border, backcolor, text and enable`.

```
private void HideButton(Button button)
{
    button.BackColor = this.BackColor;
    button.Text = string.Empty;
    button.TabStop = false;
    button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
    button.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
    button.Enabled = false;
}
```

Hope this can help you.